# Is one Arduino Uno enough for building a rover with heat sensor and proximity sensor?

Tags: arduino

Is one Arduino Uno enough for building a rover with heat sensor and proximity sensor? Is it able to perform all 3 tasks?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a "heat sensor" like a contact chip/termocouple/infrared contactless thermometer, and a sonar as "proxymity sensor" are very esay to implement with arduino.

with infrared thermometer i've seen project of thermal imaging.

Arduino DOES NOT have enought ram/cpu to do real image processing, but if you are fine with very low resolution (like 30x30 pixel, please note exponential grow) or you use arduino as "bridge" for a more performing elaboration (like send pixel over some bus to a PC) is is possible.

i've seen 600*400 photo taken by a serial camera and sent direclty back to pc in like 60 seconds, but i've also seen movement followinf done real time using the mouse's optical cmos sensor (they are like 36*36 pixel)